# How to design data vault schema for efficient queries for BPMS system?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-process-management

**Current situation:**

We have a BPMS (business process management suite) in place. There is increasing demand on historical and operative reports. The data model in the BPMS is not designed for historical queries. So we are analysing the possible solutions.

**Solution in mind:**

The idea is to push data on events in flow to an external database.  Typical events in BPM are: new process instance was created, status changed, a step in the process was performed or status of the process instance was changed. Data vault is besides the star schema one of the interesting alternatives. Let’s assume there are two Hubs: PI (processitem instances) and OU (organisational unit) and a Link table LINK_PI_OU. Each time the process item is assigned to an organisational unit a new line will be added to the link table. The LOAD_DATE in the link table contains the datetime when this record was added. The record in the link table with the latest LOAD_DATE shows the current assignment of the process instance.

**Question:**

Let’ assume the business wants to know to whom all open process instances are currently assigned grouped by organisational unit.
How will a query look like for this report? Can it really be performant? 
Or am I on the complete wrong way?

Comment: Your example query doesn't really seem like a historical query, since it is open process instances and their current assignments (presumably grouped by current OU).

Comment: Yes, you are right. The point is, that for the described schema it is easy to create a historical querry. The question is, can I use this schema for operational querries too.

Comment: @Waldermar It's going to depend a lot on your schema (and obviously the update speed of the data-warehouse from the live data). Sometimes in a DW it is difficult to do point-in-a-day when you don't have specific snapshot-style time grain because a star might be highly transactional (i.e. all the current facts don't share a common data_dt_id).  On the other hand, with a daily grain, it's usually as simple as pulling everything based on MAX(data_dt_id). I have found dimensional models to be very performant and also very easy to query compared to traditional normalized entity models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms I didnt think that Data-Vault is intended to be an end user report layer or even a faux transactional system.

Im not completely clear on your archectiture, but in my understanding D-V is a historical repository that keeps all data for an enterprise that feeds a (Kimball/Inmon)datawarehouse. So in high level terms ...

Transaction systems => D-V => DWH => (cubes =>) users

This being the case, I wouldnt be posing queries to a Data Vault, instead I would write some ETL to populate a data warehouse and pose queries at the DWH.

The other view, I guess, is that you could build a set of views on top of the D-V, that would hide the structure from users, but I think I'm a bit of a purist and would go for a DWH.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marcud D said, Data Vault is the model of Data Warehouse and usually when using DV modelling, you have to build data marts from DV for reporting purposes. I think that organizational unit should be modeled as Satellite table, not as Hub table. So, in any way, you should build a query to feed a specific data mart from DV model and then use it for reporting purposes.

Comment: Thanks for response!

_Regarding the usage of satellite instead of link:_
In the satellite table the entries are usually inserted and not updated. So the problem to find the last entry is the same as in the link table.

Comment: _Regarding data marts:_
If I understood right, a data mart is aggregated amount of data for a special purpose. To calculate this aggregation it is execution time required. In my case the data mart could be implemented as a materialised view with a query using the max() function on the LOAD_DATE in the Link table. Since this query is expensive, the data in this view can’t be always up to date.

Comment: In general the operational queries have to be executed very often and they should be very up do date. (e.g. “which process instances are currently in my org unit open?”). 
The historical queries don’t need to be very up to date. The “one hour old” state is often acceptable. 

So the question for me is, if the data vault is really the right vehicle for BPM dashboards.